# Set servlet to respond at root level? on Azure Cloud

Tags: tomcat, servlets, webserver, azure-web-app-service

My servlet name is SDK and suppose website name is **thisisfake.com**
when i visit **thisisfake.com/** page gives an error 404 not found but when i visit **thisisfake.com/SDK** my website works fine.

---

**How can i visit to my servlet directly from top domain name.**

---

**Expected output:** > When i visit **thisisfake.com/**  the page must serve output from servlet as did for http://thisisfake.com/SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Found Answer to my own question
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-get-started-java 
**In accordance with Tomcat's default behavior, filename ROOT.war in /site/wwwroot/webapps gives you the root web app (azurewebsites.net)**, and filename .war gives you a named web app (azurewebsites.net/filename).